# How to get pass a localisation issue when setting up a maven project?

Tags: kvm, ovirt, maven

I'm trying to install ovirt on my mint laptop.

Installing oVirt on a debian distribution is expirimental and there is little knowledge about troubleshooting on the web.

However, I have found the source of my issue, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

The output of the failed maven test is as follows:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.ovirt.engine.core.branding.BrandingManagerTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 11, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.249 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGetMessageDefaultLocale(org.ovirt.engine.core.branding.BrandingManagerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.016 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The result should be 'Main header' expected:<Main header[]> but was:<Main header[(fr)]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at org.ovirt.engine.core.branding.BrandingManagerTest.testGetMessageDefaultLocale(BrandingManagerTest.java:81)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

notice the 6th row: `The result should be 'Main header' expected:<Main header[]> but was:<Main header[(fr)]>`

It seems that the test failed over a string mismatch, probably because my Linux is installed in French. I want to find a way to force the installation to install only in English to avoid this. I have tried addind `BUILD-LOCALES="en"` but that did not fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So you are correct in assuming the problem is with your linux being French, this caused the default locale of your JVM to be french as well. However the unit test assumes the default is en_US as the default locale (as in it doesn't set the locale explicitly to be en_US at the start of the test run).

To solve this in your particular case, you can pass this to the make run:

DEV_EXTRA_BUILD_FLAGS='-Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en' which should pass the locale to the JVM when running the tests, and causes it to load the right properties to test against.